# how to dump model from GradientBoostingRegressor to txt?

Tags: scikit-learn

I am using gradient boosting regressor to build a predictive model.

After all the tuning/CV, finally I get my prediction right. I am now thinking about dump the model to a file, so that my production c++ program can load it and use it.

It seem that sklearn provides model persistence through pickle, but I am wondering if there is a way to convert pickle model into txt, like what xgboost has. My production code is c++ so having pickle as media is really  not handy

Is there a 'dumpModel' function in the library?

Anyone has any experience ?

Thanks